# ArrayList String compares

Tags: java, string, loops, arraylist

I have created an ArrayList that holds "accounts" created by a user. I'm now trying to write a "login" function that loops through the ArrayList and checks the user input against accounts already existing in the accounts ArrayList. This is my loop;

```
for(UserInfo createdUser : auctionAccounts){
    if(enteredUser.equals(createdUser.userName) && enteredPass.equals(createdUser.passWord)){
        System.out.println("Welcome: " +createdUser.userName);
        returnToMenu();                 
    }else{
        System.out.println("Username or Password is wrong!");
        loginAccount(aI);               
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine if there is only one account in the ArrayList. However when there is more than one account in the list, I can only ever login to the first account, and none after that.

I have also tried using the ArrayList.contains() method instead of .equals(), however this produces the same results.

EDIT: just to add, this is how I create accounts;

```
UserInfo createdUser = new UserInfo();

System.out.println("---- Enter a username ----");
createdUser.setUsername(scanner.next());

System.out.println("---- Enter a password ----");
createdUser.setPass(scanner.next());

this.aI.createAccount(createdUser); 
accountHandler(aI);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing you should do is remove the `else` portion inside your loop that tries to match usernames and passwords.

The reason is that, you don't really know if the username/pw combination is wrong **until you checked the whole list**.

However, you tell the user they entered wrong information **if what they enter doesn't match the first user in your list**.

Essentially, each time the user tries to login, you have to iterate through your whole list before determining if they entered the correct information because you have to try to match them to every existing user.

Here is how your code could look like:

```
for(UserInfo createdUser : auctionAccounts){
    if(enteredUser.equals(createdUser.userName) && enteredPass.equals(createdUser.passWord)){
        System.out.println("Welcome: " +createdUser.userName);
        returnToMenu();                 
    }
}
// if this point is reached, then username and pw are invalid
System.out.println("Username or Password is wrong!");
```

If you don't want to iterate through the whole list each time the user tries to login (since that could be quite inefficient for a large enough amount of users), you can use some sort of a `Map` that ties a username to a correct password. This would allow you for a fast look-up table and eliminate iteration over all users:

```
Map<String, UserInfo> auctionAccounts;
// initialization, your other code ...
if(auctionAccounts.get(enteredUser) != null &&                       // user with entered username exists
   auctionAccounts.get(enteredUser).password.equals(enteredPass) {   // entered password is correct
    // SUCCESSFULL LOGIN
} else {
    // INVALID USERNAME or PASSWORD
}
```